# How can I fire PHPStorm's deployment from Gulp.js

Tags: sass, phpstorm, gulp

I'm using Gulp.js to watch sass files in my project and auto-compile/minify them. I've got my PHPStorm set up to automatically deploy(upload) changed files, including external changes.

The problem I'm having is that PHPStorm doesn't recognize the external changes to files until I switch to a different app, then back to PHPStorm. Is there a way I could programmatically tell PHPStorm when to do a check for changed files?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Programmatically? Don't know. But instead of alt-tabbing just use `Synchronize` action -- it will re-read project files searching for changes.

Comment: David did you find any solution?

Comment: @AlexKneller - I have not found a good solution to this problem. :-/

Comment: I was wondering if you ever got this solved?

Answer (score 0):

you should start your gulp command with return like:

```
return gulp.src(PATHS.site_src + 'Styles/*.scss')
```

Answer (score -1):

I used rsync inside of my gulp watch task i.e.

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  var watcher = gulp.watch('/path/to/sassfile.scss', ['sass']);
  watcher.on('change', function(event) {
    console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
    gulp.src('/path/to/compiledcss.css')
      .pipe(rsync({
        hostname: 'dev.example.com',
        username: 'foo',
        progress: true,
        destination: '/path/on/remote/server'
      }));
  });
});
```

You'll need to download gulp-rsync (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rsync) and generate the correct paths, but this seems to work for me